# Create a Windows Forms application from the command line

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to follow the MSDN documentation ( [Windows Forms from Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-create-a-windows-forms-application-from-the-command-line?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) ) to create a windows forms application from a command line. I did the following:

1. Created a VB.net new project
2. Importing the following namespaces as directed in the MSDN documentation: ComponentModel, Drawing, Windows.Forms.

However I for some reason my VB code editor is not giving me the option to import the Windows.Forms namespace. See 1st pic below.

[image: Not being given the option to import Windows.Forms namespace]

Also when I forcefully type it out I get the following warning message with a green squiggly line (see the second pic below). Can anyone pls tell me where I am going wrong?

[image: Warning message when I forcefully type it out]

The MSDN link as the next steps ask me to write the following piece of code: `Public Class Form1 Inherits Form`
Unless I include the Windows.Forms namespace the above code piece is giving me an error. So pls point out where I am going wrong?

When I created the project I selected the following option:

[image: Console App (.Net core)]

Comment: it looks like you created a project for WPF instead of Windows Forms. If you include in your question which version of Visual Studio you are using we might be able to help you further

Comment: Do you need to create a Form from the Command Line (write that code in, e.g., Notepad, compile it and run the executable), or do you need to create a WinForms application using Visual Studio as editor / helper? If you want to build WinForms app, just pick that template from the Desktop templates available, when you create a new Solution in Visual Studio, so you'll get all the base assemblies needed already added in the main Project's References.

Comment: @Jimi...Form from the command line...not creating a WPF application

Comment: @JayV ...i did not create a WPF ....I created a console app (.Netcore). Have edited the qustion to include the image of the selection made while creating the project. Also I am using Visual Studio 2019. Community Edition

Comment: I'm not going to tell you not to do it this way, Sougata, if it's what you want to do, but you can create a VB .NET WinForms project in .NET Core as simply as `dotnet new winforms --language=VB`.

Comment: @RyanLundy I agree . But i am trying to learn about windows forms and was following the MSDN documentation that I have mentioned in my question . But got stuck and hence asked.

Comment: Any help guys? Would help me a lot if anybody can pls point out my mistake.

Comment: Do you want to create a stand-alone executable Form compiling a class from the Command Line, or do you want to show a Form in a Console app? Two different things, not exactly related. It's not really useful to build a .Net Core Console app if you the want to include a Form. Maybe build a Windows Forms app and then change its `Application Type` to `Console`. -- The real intention - what this application is meant for - count more than other stuff.

Comment: @Jimi I am just trying to learns FORMS in VB. Thats all. For that I started reading the documentation and got stuck. Hence I posted the question. There is no end goal except for learning the topic.

Comment: Open up Visual Studio. Pick `Create new Project..`, select the `Windows Forms App (.Net Framework)` Template. You cannot find the Template? Then open up Visual Studio's Installer (you should have a link in the same page) and, from the `Workloads`, select the `.Net Desktop Development` package group and install what's missing.